# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when running a model or compute() a spark table

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am working on a group project for an exam in which we are required to analyse a dataset with 7 millions of rows and more than 30 columns. We've been learning sparklyr since last month.

We don't have any cluster available and the code of our analysis needs to run in different computers, with different setups and operating system.

After we import the dataset, we run some transformations and create new variables and drop some other. To keep the data as light as possible in terms of memory I've been using sdf_register() for intermediate results and compute() when I finished to manipulate the dataset to insert the Spark table in the Spark cache, ready for run some linear model.

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
# spark connection ####
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = system("/usr/libexec/java_home -V", intern = T))
connection <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
# import airline dataset ####
data.folder <- "/airlinebefore2009"
system.time(complete.data <- spark_read_csv(
  path = data.folder, sc = connection, name = "airlineDataset"))

complete.data %>%
  group_by(ORIGIN, DEST) %>%
  mutate(speed = (DISTANCE*1.60934)/(AIR_TIME/60)) %>%
  filter(CANCELLED == 0 & DIVERTED == 0 & speed>300 & speed<990) %>%
  na.replace(LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY=0, SECURITY_DELAY=0, NAS_DELAY=0, WEATHER_DELAY=0, CARRIER_DELAY=0) %>%
  select(ORIGIN, DEST, DEP_DELAY, DEP_DEL15, TAXI_OUT, TAXI_IN, 
         ARR_DELAY, ARR_DEL15, CANCELLED, DIVERTED, CRS_ELAPSED_TIME,
         AIR_TIME, DISTANCE, CARRIER_DELAY, WEATHER_DELAY, NAS_DELAY,
         SECURITY_DELAY, LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY) %>%
  sdf_register('airlinedataset')

... some transformation similar to the next code block...

no.issue.flights <- tbl(connection, 'airlinedataset') %>%
  group_by(ORIGIN, DEST)%>% 
  mutate(percentile = ifelse(DEP_DEL15 == 0 & ARR_DEL15 == 0, 
                             percent_rank(AIR_TIME), NA),
         airtimeNA = ifelse(percentile > 0.9 | percentile < 0.1, NA, AIR_TIME), 
         mean_air_time = mean(airtimeNA, na.rm = T),
         new_air_time = AIR_TIME - mean_air_time, 
         frequenza = ifelse(DEP_DEL15 == 0 & ARR_DEL15 == 0, 1, 0),
         sum_frequenza = sum(frequenza, na.rm = T)) %>%
  filter(sum_frequenza > 5) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ARR_DEL15, DEP_DEL15, new_taxi_out, new_taxi_in, new_air_time, DEP_DELAY, ARR_DELAY, 
         WEATHER_DELAY, NAS_DELAY, CARRIER_DELAY, SECURITY_DELAY, LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY) %>%
  compute('onlygoodflights')
```

Because I put `no.issue.flights` into the Spark cache by `compute()` I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` sometimes.

But if I run the following part of the code, without putting `no.issue.flights` in the cache, I get the same `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error or I get `R session aborted` when I run the following linear models:

```r
# 1st model ####
del1arr0 <- no.issue.flights %>% 
  filter(DEP_DELAY>16 & ARR_DELAY<16) 
partitions <- del1arr0 %>% 
  sdf_random_split(training = 0.7, test = 0.3, seed = 1111)
training_set <- partitions$training
test_set <- partitions$test

lm_model <- training_set %>%
              ml_linear_regression(ARR_DELAY ~ DEP_DELAY + new_taxi_out + new_taxi_in + new_air_time) 

# 2nd model ###
del1arr1 <- no.issue.flights %>% 
  filter(DEP_DELAY>15 & ARR_DELAY>15) 
partitions <- del1arr1 %>% 
  sdf_random_split(training = 0.7, test = 0.3, seed = 1111)
training_set <- partitions$training
test_set <- partitions$test
lm_model <- training_set %>%
              ml_linear_regression(ARR_DELAY ~ DEP_DELAY + new_taxi_out + new_taxi_in + new_air_time)
```

If the dataset part code runs without errors, sometimes I still get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error after running the 1st model or the 2nd one. I don't understand why this happens.

---

My computer is a MacBook Pro 2010 with 8GB RAM and has 500GB SSD

```
spark_config()
$sparklyr.connect.csv.embedded
[1] "^1.*"

$spark.sql.catalogImplementation
[1] "hive"

$sparklyr.connect.cores.local
[1] 4

$spark.sql.shuffle.partitions.local
[1] 4
```